# Virtual function must return a value in MS C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, design-patterns

I have a base class `Animal` and two derived classes `Bird` and `Fish`. I have two virtual functions, `fly(int)` and `swim(int)` in `Animal` for `Bird` and `Fish` respectively. There is a common function `aliveSince()` in `Animal`

```
class Animal{
public:
  Animal() {
    age = 0;
  }
  virtual ~Animal(){}
  static Animal* factory(int type);
  int aliveSince(){
    return age;
  }
  virtual int fly(int m){} //error, needs a return value
  virtual int swim(int m){} //error, needs a return value

private:
  int age;
};

class Bird: public Animal{
public:
  Bird(){
    totalFlight = 0;
  }
  int fly(int m){
    cout<<"Bird flew "<<m<<" metres\n";
    return totalFlight = totalFlight+m;
  }
private:
  int totalFlight;
};

class Fish: public Animal{
public:
  Fish(){
    totalSwim = 0;
  }
  int swim(int m){
    cout<<"Fish swam "<<m<<" metres underground\n";
    return totalSwim = totalSwim + m;
  }
private:
  int totalSwim;
};

Animal* Animal::factory(int type){
    if (type) return new Bird();
    else return new Fish();
}
```

I want to use the these classes like this:

```
Animal *a = Animal::factory(1); //Bird
Animal *b = Animal::factory(0); //Fish
a->aliveSince();
b->aliveSince();
a->fly(5);
b->swim(5);
```

I am compiling in MS VC++ and it generates errors, `Animal::fly` and `Animal::swim` needs a return value. However, this compiles fine in GNU C++.
How can I get rid of the error without having to specify a return value in the virtual methods?

Note that I can't make these functions **pure virtual** as it would make the Animal class abstract and all derived classes will need to implement `fly()` and `swim()`

Comment: You probably wanted to write `virtual int fly(int m) = 0;`

Comment: Will it not make the `Animal` class abstract in such a case, which I can't make? I have already specified this in the problem statement.

Comment: _"Note that I can't make these functions pure virtual as it would make the Animal class abstract "_ Then you must return some reasonable default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Just saw you can't use pure virtual methods because you need some default.

If you need a default, you'd better return it explicitly, instead of letting the compiler (or chance) decide the return value. So just return 0.

ORIGINAL

If you don't supply any implementation in your base class, use [Pure Virtual](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/pure-virtual-function/) methods. Like so:

```c++
class Animal
{
public:
  virtual int fly(int m) = 0;
  virtual int swim(int m) = 0;
};
```

A Pure-Virtual method is a method that has no body. It makes the `Animal` base class abstract - you will not be able to construct any instances of it, just of derived classes that implement these methods.

Comment: Let us say, if I make these methods pure virtual, will I need to define method `fly` in the `Fish` class or can I avoid it?

Comment: I guess I will need to define all the virtual methods in the derived class, otherwise, it won't let me instantiate the `Bird` or `Fish` objects?

Comment: All concrete classes will need to have implementations (either themselves or in a base class).

Comment: The compiler will not provide a default. Not returning is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions need to return a value, as you have guessed:

```
virtual int fly(int m){ return 0; }
virtual int swim(int m){ return 0; }
```

Either, put in return 0; in both scopes. That would be your answer 'as you are asking'.

Or try somything like this to simplify your code:

```
class Animal{
public:
  Animal()
  {
    totalMoved = 0;
  }
  virtual ~Animal(){}
  virtual int move( int m )
  {
    totalMoved += m;
    cout<<"Total distance " << totalMoved << std::endl;
    return totalMoved ;
  }

protected:
  int totalMoved;
};

class Bird: public Animal{
public:
  int move(int m)
  {
    cout<<"Bird flew "<<m<<" metres\n";
    return Animal::move( m );
  }
};

class Fish: public Animal{
public:
  int swim(int m){
    cout<<"Fish swam "<<m<<" metres underground\n";
    return Animal::move( m );
  }
};
```

Specific algorithms to move can be written within the Bird and Fish class. The totalMove could be shared, so share it. That is the concept of OOP programming and leaves you out of doing things double.

Have added the console output in Animal too, so you can see what happens when.

Comment: You could come up with a `move` function in such a case. This was just a simplified example I had created. It will not be always possible to do something like this in a big project. For instance, I am trying to implement derived classes for FTP and SFTP using a base class FileTransfer and some functionalities are very different in the two protocols.

Comment: Then your example doesn't fit. Functionality is written within Fish::move() and in Bird::move(), still totalMove (or totalUploadBytes) would/could be shared. Not calling Animal::move() in both would give the descendant classes 100% their own functionality, making the descendant responsible to add to totalMoved themselves. But do call Animal::move(), could (considering the FTP/SFTP) handle some events that are shared.

Comment: events such as, std::function< void(BytesReceived&) > OnBytesReceived; if( OnBytesReceived ) OnBytesReceived();

Comment: Well, yes. They do have some shared events, which is why we have the base class `FileTransfer` at the first place, just like `aliveSince()` in `Animal` class. 
Thanks for your answer. It is indeed mandatory to specify a return value in the virtual function if we don't want to make the base class Abstract. That does make sense since compiler won't know what to return.